# How Can I Separate Two Input Integers?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm not very old in programming,
I wanna input a number (`n`) and depending on it, I wanna input n integers separated with one space using
while loop(e.g)
I tried:

```py
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

but I found that I can input number of integers exceed the value n

Very hopeful to help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you only want the first `n` you can do `list(map(int, input().split()))[:n]`

Comment: I'm using a counter and every time I decrement it, I'm allowed to input new integer until the counter reaches zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this in 2 main easy ways:

1. accept an arbitrary input, split it an take the first n values there and/or throw an error/message if you get a different number of entries

   ```
    n = int(input("pick a number: "))
    list_number =  list(map(int, input(f"enter {n} numbers").split())) 
    if len(list_number)==n:
        print("cool")
        #do your stuff
    else:
        print("not cool")
        #do something about it
   ```
2. take the numbers one at the time and repeat this n times, for that you need to specify the number of loops you want to do, which is make easy with the use of `range(n)` which produce a serie of number from 0 to n-1:

   ```
    >>> list(range(5))
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    >>>
   ```

   but what is relevant here is that we get n elements, so something like this for example:

   ```
    n = int(input("pick a number: "))
    list_number=[]
    for i in range(n): 
        list_number.append(int(input("enter a number: ")))
    #do your stuff
   ```

Also check this [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) for a more detailed example

Answer (score 0):

More "pythonic" than chaining `list` and `map` would be a list comprehension:

```
user_input = input()
a = [int(s) for s in user_input.split()]
```

Then take the `n` first elements of this list as suggested by @Moosefeather in the comments. You should wrap the whole thing in a `try/except` block to catch `ValueError`s if anything in the input is not an integer, or `IndexError`s if the given input is not long enough.